# Using bundleDependencies in npm when your bundles have dependencies

Tags: node.js, dependencies, package, npm

Note: you can reproduce this precisely by running `npm install hotplate`.
I am writing hotplate, a simple module that is plugin-based:

https://github.com/mercmobily/hotplate

It's basically a small module, and then a whole lot of "plugin" modules which get loaded. Please note that because of this huge file system reshuffling hotplate is not currently functional.

Now... basically the structure is:

```
hotplate
|
 - hotplate.js
 - package.json
 - node_modules
   |
   - hotCoreClientFiles
   - hotCorePage
   - hotCoreSharedCode
   - hotDojoAuth
     ...
```

Hotplate then loads the relevant "plugins" (depending on what the user wants to do) etc. These plugins are to be bundled with the main module.
Now... I am having a lot of grief figuring out how to automatically load the plugin's dependencies.
This is what package.json looks like:

```
{
  "name": "hotplate",
  "description": "Hotplate SaaS development framework",
  "version": "0.0.13",
  "private": false,
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "3.x",
    "async": "*",

    "hotCoreClientFiles": "*",
     [...]
    "hotDojoSubmit": "*",
    "hotDojoWidgetHooks": "*",
    "hotDojoWidgets": "*",
    "hotMongoAuth": "*",
    "hotMongoCometMessages": "*",
    "hotMongoLogger": "*"

  },
  "bundleDependencies": [
    "hotCoreClientFiles",
     [...]
    "hotDojoSubmit",
    "hotDojoWidgetHooks",
    "hotDojoWidgets",
    "hotMongoAuth",
    "hotMongoCometMessages",
    "hotMongoLogger"
  ],
}
```

Basically, some of the sub-modules also have dependencies (outlined in their own package.json files); after installation, this is the result:

```
/home/chiara
└─┬ hotplate@0.0.12
  ├── async@0.2.6
  ├─┬ express@3.1.0
  [...]
  ├── hotCoreClientFiles@0.0.4
  ├── hotCoreCommonValidators@0.0.4
  ├── hotCoreError@0.0.4
  [...]
  ├── hotDojoWidgets@0.0.4
  ├─┬ hotMongoAuth@0.0.4
  │ ├── UNMET DEPENDENCY allhttperrors *
  │ ├── UNMET DEPENDENCY bcrypt *
  │ ├── UNMET DEPENDENCY hat *
  │ ├── UNMET DEPENDENCY mongowrapper *
  │ └── UNMET DEPENDENCY simpleschema-mongo *
  ├─┬ hotMongoCometMessages@0.0.4
  │ ├── UNMET DEPENDENCY allhttperrors *
  │ └── UNMET DEPENDENCY mongowrapper *
  └─┬ hotMongoLogger@0.0.4
    ├── UNMET DEPENDENCY jsonreststores-mongo *
    ├── UNMET DEPENDENCY mongowrapper *
    └── UNMET DEPENDENCY simpledeclare *
```

This is not good! If you then run `npm update`... well, a bit of a disaster happens.
The module `mongowrapper` depends on `mongodb`, which gets downloaded and compiled N times.

I don't really want to set `mongodb`, `mongowrapper`, `simpledeclare` etc. as dependencies as the main `hotplate` module because... well, because they are not. Hotplate is only a loader. If `simpledeclare` is already required by a package on a higher level, then OK it won't need to be installed again. Otherwise, I would like it to stay in the sub module's `node_modules` directory.

Now, I must be doing something very wrong. I just cannot figure out what it is...

Thank you!

Merc.

Answer (score -3):

The bundleDependencies field is to be used in your plugins package.json. Not your main loader.

Comment: ...? Uh? Can you please be clearer about this? If I take them out of bundledDependencies, things won't work because npm will ignore them when I try to npm publish them. So, they need to be listed there. Not sure what you mean exactly...

Comment: My bad, Since you were having problems with a plugin based architecture, I thought you meant the new `peerDependencies`.